# Encapsulating dynamic mouse UI element in WPF appliation

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mvvm

I am developing a C# WPF application utilizing MVVM pattern

In my app user via mouse (or touchscreen) sets offset values for the Pan-Tilt Motor. Since movement should be somwhat percise, I decided to create a UI helper element, which currently looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

I want it to look nice and dandy, so that values wont be obscured or intersected with other lines:

[image: obscured or intersected with other lines]

But at the same time I want to stick to MVVM pattern, and such behaviour, although not hard to implement per se, requires a lot of bindings, logic and triggers. That clutters my XAML and View Model a lot, so here comes my question:

What is the common way/best practice of encapsulating such element (which is basically a complex dynamic figure) into some abstract form, hiding all irrelevant to the main app logic within it?

The desired solution wold look something like this:

```
<canvas>
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <!--MouseUp, MouseDown, MouseMove Commands...-->
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>

   <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <!--Getting Mouse X and Y values...-->
   </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

   <MouseUI MouseUiClass="{Binding MouseUiClass}"/>
     or
   <MouseUI Start="{Binding MouseUiClass.Start}"
            End="{Binding MouseUiClass.End}"
            IsFinished="{Binding MouseUiClass.IsFinished}"/>
</canvas>
```

I did consider to use `UserControl` but I struggle to understand how to properly display it because dynamically resizes, and start and end point can be placed in any part of canvas.

Comment: `UserControl` is a good way to encapsulate the UI-related XAML and code in one place. I would do the positioning of the labels in code-behind. It doesn't break MVVM because it's purely UI-related code.

Comment: Honestly I would just draw that text with a thick white outline so the lines don't affect readability. Other than that, as for encapsulating this logic, if you like XAML then UserControl, if you prefer C# then a custom behavior or attached property (though I prefer behaviors).